# Pulseaudio won't allow more than one application to play sound

Tags: release-freya, sound

I haven't changed anything audio management related since installing elementary OS 0.3.2, but I have to refresh Youtube videos (or pages they are embedded in) in Firefox to get them to play.

This isn't a Flash-only thing because other programs do it too. if I use Clementine and open a game or similar sound producing application, Clementine moves to the next song and throws the following error:

"pa_stream_writeable_size() failed: Connection Terminated"

About the time this error shows up, apport reports that Pulseaudio Sound system KDE Routing Policy has closed unexpectedly.

Anyone else have this issue? Would reinstalling elementary OS fix it?

Comment: What did you do last?

Comment: I installed common applications I use and two plugin sets for gstreamer from the main software repository. I'm not using the proposed repos, and these programs didn't cause problems before reinstalling elementary.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

It will reinstall pulseaudio.

Comment: That command doesn't reinstall packages, but I did do so with synaptic and even cleared out the configuration and temp files for pulse. It seems to be fixed, but I'm going to keep testing it because last time I thought it was fixed pulse started acting up again.